# How to get value from another record in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure. How can create a view or create a select statement adding a column showing the value from another record of the same notice# field in the same table.

```
ID   notice#       notice Date         Sequence
1    ABCD1          1/2/2021                   1
2    ABCD1          1/3/2021                   2
3    ABCD1          1/3/2021                   3
4    ABCD2          1/3/2021                   1
5    ABCD2          1/3/2021                   2
```

Expected result: I want to add a new column Prior notice date as

```
ID   notice#        notice Date    Sequence      Prior Noice Date
1    ABCD1          1/2/2021          1           
2    ABCD1          1/3/2021          2           1/2/2021 
3    ABCD1          1/3/2021          3           1/3/2021
4    ABCD2          1/3/2021          1
5    ABCD2          1/3/2021          2           1/3/2021
```

- If Sequence 1 then Prior Noice Date = null
- If Sequence 2 then Prior Noice Date = SO Date of Sequence 1
- If Sequence 3 then Prior Noice Date = SO Date of Sequence 2

Comment: @DaleK Sorry about that i mentioned i am looking to create a view or write a select statement

Comment: OK, you just need to show us what you tried and where you got stuck then.

Comment: You probably want to checkout window functions.

Comment: Your row #6 sequence number changed from your sample data to your desired results.

Comment: My bad I will fix it. Thanks @DaleK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a subquery solution:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [notice#],
    [notice Date],
    Sequence,
    (SELECT [notice Date]
     FROM YourTable yt2
     WHERE yt2.Sequence = yt1.Sequence - 1
         AND yt2.[notice#] = yt1.[notice#]) as [Prior Noice Date]
FROM YourTable yt1
```

Answer (score 6):

LAG/LEAD functions can be used to achieve this.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df7f2/4

```
select *, lag([notice date]) over (partition by notice# order by [sequence]) 
from table1
order by notice#, [sequence];
```